# Plotting spatial data with varying line width and color according to additional variables

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, line, spatial

I have a bunch of spatial points which I want to plot as a line on a map. I wonder if there is an easy way to vary the line width according to another variable, i.e. the altitude of the locations. Same problem for the color of the line. Is there a way to give the line a varying color, depending on the distance between successive points.

One odd way might be to draw a single line for each to consecutive points. Anyways, it would be nice to have smooth transition between line widths and colors, which probably won't be possible for that solution.

What I am looking for is kind of a combination of the following two plots:

```
    df<-data.frame(c(13,13.2,13.5,13.4), c(53.0,53.2,53.3,52.8),c(12,14,14,19), c(4,6,7,8))  
    colnames(df)<-c("x", "y", "height", "speed")

    qplot(df$x, df$y, color = df$speed, size = df$height)  
    plot(df$x, df$y, type = "l", col = df$height, lwd = df$speed)
```

Comment: Maybe add some code of what you've tried. For example, this may be easier if you are using `ggplot` or some other graphics library, rather than `base`, but we don't know what you're using

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ggplot, still willing to learn of course

Comment: smooth transitions for line widths are going to be very hard in ggplot2.